# How to identify devices acting as routers, ie, forwarding packets using SNMP queries?

Tags: networking, snmp, router, packets, mib

Using SNMP queries to the MIB-II objects, how to identify devices acting as routers, ie, forwarding packets?

The only way to identify them is through the identifier, type or description, or can I identify it through the packet traffic?

Answer (score 1):

If you're only looking to tell whether or not they forward traffic, then there is actually a MIB object to tell you just that:

```
IP-MIB::ipForwarding
ipForwarding OBJECT-TYPE
  -- FROM       IP-MIB
  SYNTAX        INTEGER {forwarding(1), notForwarding(2)} 
  MAX-ACCESS    read-write
  STATUS        current
  DESCRIPTION   "The indication of whether this entity is acting as an IPv4
            router in respect to the forwarding of datagrams received
            by, but not addressed to, this entity.  IPv4 routers forward
            datagrams.  IPv4 hosts do not (except those source-routed
            via the host).

            When this object is written, the entity should save the
            change to non-volatile storage and restore the object from
            non-volatile storage upon re-initialization of the system.
            Note: a stronger requirement is not used because this object
            was previously defined."
::= { iso(1) org(3) dod(6) internet(1) mgmt(2) mib-2(1) ip(4) 1 }
```

Comment: I think it's just that.

Sorry if this question sounded like a stupid question, but am new to networking, so it can be a bit confusing.

Thank you.

Comment: That's ok; it'd be really hard to know of every MIB variable that existed.  And if you haven't seen much before, how would you know without asking?